# Rails Mailer: Pass `attachments` to other methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pass-by-reference, scoping

I'm working on a standard Rails app that uses a mailer to send email.

Each mailer class has an `attachments` attribute [[src on GitHub](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/base.rb#L749)] that aliases an instance variable.

I'm trying to pass that `attachments` reference to a function defined in `helpers/yeet.rb`, but inside the helper `attachments` does not behave the way it does in the mailer scope.

My Question: How can I interact with `attachments` and do things like `attachments.inline['a.png'] = URI.open('a.png').read` in the helper function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, given the Github source for `attachments` I just needed to add:

```
attr_reader :_message
attr_writer :_message
```

Then I could pass `self` as an argument to the function defined in the helper, and inside that helper function, I was able to access `mailer_self._message.attachments` and mutate the attachments directly. (`mailer_self` is the variable name of the positional argument in the helper function to which I passed `self` in the mailer function itself).